# HttpUriRequest#addHeader(...) is eradicating my entity

Tags: android, http-request

I'm talking to a webservice in Android using basic auth.  This means I am sending a header looking like

```
Authorization Basic [user:pass base 64 string here]
```

I'm setting up my request thus:

```
public CreateUserService(Intent intent, int id) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    super(id);
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", intent.getStringExtra(FeedIntentService.EXTRA_UID)));
    //and so on.

    setupRequest(null, params);
}
```

and then in a superclass I have a method

```
protected void setupRequest(List<Header> headers, List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    mRequest = new HttpPost(getUri());
    mRequest.addHeader(new BasicHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + AUTH_STRING));
    //AUTH_STRING = the base 64 encoded user:pass pair
    if(headers!=null) {
        for(Header h: headers) {
            mRequest.addHeader(h);
        }
    }
    if(params!=null)
        ((HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase) mRequest).setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
}
```

The trouble is the server isn't receiving my request body.  I read the request in fiddler and indeed it seems to be missing.  However, when I *remove* the line

```
    mRequest.addHeader(new BasicHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + AUTH_STRING);
```

and look at the request in fiddler, I can see the body just as I would have expected, though obviously the server rejects the unauthorized request.

The AUTH_STRING is being encoded like this:

```
private static final String APP_KEY = "user";
private static final String APP_SECRET = "pass";
private static final String APP_STRING = APP_KEY + ":" + APP_SECRET;
private static final String APP_BASE_64 = Base64.encodeToString( APP_STRING.getBytes() , Base64.DEFAULT );
```

Comment: Have you verified that the base64 encoded result is valid? Try making a request via curl using that Header.. curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic <the base64-encoded string>" <server Url Here>

Comment: It seems to be, because I'm getting error strings back from the server saying I haven't included mandatory parameters (which I haven't, because the entity is missing).  When the auth header is invalid I get a 401 message.

Comment: Aha!  Changing the auth string to be the unencoded one brings back the entity, though!  I think you're on to something!  (Possibly the Base 64 string is null terminated?)

Comment: The base 64 string ends in a newline.  Feel free to write this up as an answer and I'll set it as correct :)

Comment: @kwazi I've written you up some more context; adding a .trim() to the last line worked :) Thanks, that turned out to be it

Comment: I'm glad that worked out :-) I've (formally) added my answer with one adjustment to your fix. Please accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just following up on my comment that lead to your solution.

In most cases, I find that when the base64-encoded String in the Auth header is invalid, servers tend to behave strangely. So verify that the Authorization Header is correct.

In general, it's always best to try these kinds of things with curl first. The following is an example command with curl

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic <base64-encoded String>" http://some.server.url.com/some-endpoint
```

I see you added trim() to fix it. The real solution is to use Base64.NO_WRAP (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html#NO_WRAP). So you want to do this when encoding:

```
Base64.encodeToString( APP_STRING.getBytes() , Base64.NO_WRAP );
```

I should have probably noticed that the first time around but either way, I'm glad my first thought lead to your answer :-)

Comment: Fiddler seemed to think the entity was missing too; is newline used as a terminator?